# Failed to instantiate module ui.grid.validate

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to add validation to ui.grid.
I injected 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.validate' to my module. still it's throwing the error.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.grid.validate due to:
ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined

Below is my code:

```
var milesApp = angular.module("milesApp", [ "ui.grid", 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.gird.validate', 'ngStorage', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ngJsonExportExcel', "ngProgress", '720kb.datepicker', 'ngDialog']);
```

Comment: The validation functionality is in a very early Alpha stage, I believe. So unless you are using the very latest release candidate it may not even be included in whatever ui.grid you are using.

Comment: Hi Scott. Now i am referring the latest release and it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a misprint in a dependency name. It should be `ui.grid.validate`.

```
var milesApp = angular.module("milesApp", [ "ui.grid", 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.gird.validate', 'ngStorage', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ngJsonExportExcel', "ngProgress", '720kb.datepicker', 'ngDialog']);
```

Comment: Thanks Aliaksandr. I changed it, but still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Now i am referring the latest release and it's working. Thanks.